# Can connect to local master but not remote, pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I'm trying out [this example](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-scale/howto/spark-basic/) from `anaconda` docs:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/Snow/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark')

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('local[*]')
conf.setAppName('spark')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

def mod(x):
    import numpy as np
    return (x, np.mod(x, 2))

rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000)).map(mod).take(10)
```

Locally the script runs fine, without errors. When I change the line `conf.setMaster('local[*]')` to `conf.setMaster('spark://remote_ip:7077')` I get the error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
> : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
> at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)

Why is this happening? I also added `SPARK_MASTER_HOST=remote_ip` and
`SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077` to `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load_spark_env.sh`.

My spark version is `3.0.1` and server is `3.0.0`

I can ping the `remote_ip`.